# Images in JSP page do not display on first load (cleared cache)

Tags: html, jsp, j-security-check

I have a web app running on tomcat that requires a user to login via j_security_check.  The page redirects the user to a login.jsp page if they are not logged in.  I added some images to the jsp and these images do not appear on the page if it is the initial load of the page with a clear cache.

Then if I log in to the page, I am somehow redirected to the background image used on the login.jsp page.

If I close the browse and reopen and go to the login.jsp page, all the images appear as they should and the Login button redirects me to the appropriate page that is in the index.jsp page (which is a redirect)

I assume the images load the 2nd time because they are in the cache, but why dont they appear the first time?  And why I am mysteriously redirected to the png file used as the background if the login works fine 2nd time around.

I am totally baffled by this behavior....

Answer (score 0):

[How to import an image into a JSP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRUDf.png)

When you use relative paths for your image URLs in your JSP, they are resolved based on the current URL. If the initial URL you're accessing is different from the URL where the images are located, the relative paths might not work as expected. This could lead to images not being loaded correctly or being redirected to a different resource.

Comment: Thats a good thought, but I have another image in the same folder that loads fine onto the initial page.  Also, why would the image in question load the 2nd time?  The path is the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).